# Reading current memory image from a micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, memory, board, flash-memories

I have the MPLAB XPress Evaluation Board, which has the `PIC16F18855` microcontroller on it. The way to program it is just to copy a `.hex` file through the serial connection, which makes the bootloader update its memory image.

Is there a way to directly read the current memory image of the microcontroller? In other words, how is it possible to dump the memory image of a microcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use a microcontroller that has a debug port (e.g. JTAG, in case of ARM microcontrollers often SWD) and an appropriate debugger, or you'll need to write software for the microcontroller that outputs the memory contents e.g. via a serial interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a part I am familiar with, but the the Microchip [Bootloader Generator Users Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001779B.pdf) seems (if in fact applicable) to suggest that for this part:

- Any bootloader is an ordinary and customizable program that has to be flashed, not a fixed ROM feature
- Memory readback support exists in the code but is by default disabled for security
- The "Unified Bootloader Application" provided to fulfill the need for host side software to interface with the bootloader does not support readback, so you would need to come up with your own.

Keep in mind that while extracting a .hex file or other binary format gives you something that can be saved and reinstalled, and to some degree studied, it is not source code so not really a replacement for saving the original sources, preferably in a version control system.